# Check if a function solve an ODE using mathematica

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE (suppose is it $y''(x)+e^x y'(x)+\sin(x)y(x)=3$), and I have a function $u$. How can I use matematica to see if $u$ solve my ODE or not ? Is there a possibility ? Of course I can do it by hand, but in my case is a very very complicate ODE, so matematica would be useful for me.

Comment: Sure, for example you would write the solution, u[x_]:= Exp[x] Sin[x] + 2x^2 - 1, then just do FullSimplify[u''[x] + Exp[x] u'[x] + Sin[x] u[x]]. Then compare to the RHS (there are slicker ways - you can ask on the Mathematica Stack Exchange), but for most problems, the previous gets the job done.

Comment: i think there is no explicit solution